# Improve firebase token verification speed

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a REST api that retrieves user data. In order to access this data a validated token is required. I am using [firebase admin SDK for php](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/authentication.html#initializing-the-auth-component) for this process. The following happens:

1. Client creates token with Firebase
2. Client sends token with php REST api call
3. Firebase validates token
4. api returns data

## Problem

Step 3 (shown in code) is the problem here: it takes 3 to 5 seconds for the server to respond. The following code is responsible for this process

```
try {
    $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($idTokenString);  // 3 to 5 seconds(!)
} catch (FailedToVerifyToken $e) {
    echo 'The token is invalid: '.$e->getMessage();
}
...
  *omitted*
...
```

### Scenario

Waiting for validation on initializing the app is not that much of a problem, but the user's data is refreshable throughout the app's runtime and I do not want to have another validation process taking 3 to 5 seconds during runtime.

### Approaches made

I considered using cookies but since I have no idea where these cookies are stored I checked the document and it states the following:

> Firebase Auth provides server-side session cookie management for
> traditional websites that rely on session cookies.

and my REST api calls is not considered a traditional website.

For a very short moment I considered to store the validated status locally on the user's phone, but that makes no sense since it needs to call my php file and I can't simply pass 'userIsValidated' to this call cause obviously hackers will also be able to do so.

## Question

Is it possible to reduce any of this validation time? If not, am I able to somehow work with cookies?

Comment: Just to check, are you sure that it is specifically the `$auth->verifyIdToken()` call that takes seconds to execute, or is it just the response time of the server? This is not clear from your question. Establishing what exactly causes the slow response is important.

Comment: yes i am certain about that, this has also been tested

Comment: You are certain about what?

Comment: "are you sure that it is specifically the $auth->verifyIdToken()"   <-  about this part I am certain

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to reduce the impact of verification is to cache the decoded token and reuse that on subsequent requests. Several of Firebase's own servers use this approach to good effect.

If you use the (hash of the) encoded token as the key for the cache, and the decoded token as its value, you will automatically end up using any updated token you get for the same user.

Comment: But since this is a REST api call, is it even possible to cache something like that? They are loose php files that get a call: do their task but AFAIK store no temp data (or cache)

Comment: Caching does not require that you have persistent in-memory storage, but merely that you have a storage option that is faster than the API call. You could store the on disk in a temporary directory, or even in a local or cloud hosted database.

Answer (score 0):

On initial successful login, create a temporary token using method of your liking on the server like random characters then ship it to your client, I like to keep such temporary tokens in in-memory databases but any storage method should suffice,

Keep track of ID Tokens and Temporary Tokens with respect to their users, Now for every login or a request, client can use that token to authenticate and you can decide to check for `Firebase ID Token Revocation` in the background or periodically, which if revoked can be used to force client into sending fresh ID Token,
More on: [Detect ID token revocation in the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_the_sdk)

Notice the *additional checkRevoked boolean flag*